# No applicable technologies for standard education

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On careers, for non-technical education (or also non-technical work experience), having to specify technologies does not really make sense. I want to add my school leaving certificate but of course standard school has little to do with computer science or specific technologies, so there is not really anything I can (or want) to list there.

But the system keeps bugging me to add something:

> [education] needs technologies listed

I already wrote a text into the “achievements” section explaining what I learned, so there is nothing to add.

I would suggest that you either remove the “requirement” to list technologies there completely, or add a check box to mark something as non-technical. I am sure others have this problem as well, when they list previous work experiences that are not related to e.g. what job they are currently looking for.

Comment: When the system says your profile isn't complete & something about unlocking your profile by completing it, this becomes a massive stumbling block and source of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is needed. When filling out your profile we don't require you to put in tags. You can even leave it blank. You can also create any tag you want, they don't have to be based on SO tags. My background is not programming, mostly IT support so I have lots of non standard tags in my profile.

Now as far as the "system keeps bugging me" it's just a friendly reminder, I don't really see it as nagging you. Mine has said that for months and I pay no attention to it. Also, employers don't see your completion score or those reminders; it's simply a checklist we provide to you to help you fill out you profile as completely as possible.

**UPDATE** as JacobM said below, you be as creative as possible when creating tags. They don't have to be related to a technology at all.

Comment: Maybe then the issue is that the name of the list shouldn't be "technologies" but rather "skills" or something else more general.  I think it's totally appropriate to add non-technical skills such as "collaboration" or "research" that you might have learned at school.

Comment: As long as we're a tech specific job board, I think technologies is the correct wording.